# How do I automatically export NFS shares on reboot?

Tags: mount, nfs

I inherited a small network where each machine is an NFS server/client, and exports a /data folder to all the other machines. I've added a machine that I'd like to have the same functionality, and updated the networks /etc/fstab and /etc/exports accordingly.

However upon reboot, the new machine does not automatically create the export table, so I have to manually `sudo exportfs -a` for that machine, then `sudo mount -a` on the clients to get them connected. I've already added the shares to /etc/exports, as some articles have suggested. What is the default behavior for NFS? It doesn't appear that the old machines have a /etc/profile line for exporting the shares ... at least not that I can find.

How can I get the new machine, which is Ubuntu 12.04, to export its shares automatically on reboot?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your Distro. Maybe

```
systemctl enable nfsserver.service
```

or

```
insserv nfsserver
```

or

```
chkconfig nfsserver on
```

If your service is called "nfsserver" at all. You may find the right one by

```
find /etc/init.d /usr/lib/systemd/  -iname "*nfs*"
```

Comment: Distro is ubuntu 12.04. Result of find is /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server

Comment: `service nfs-kernel-server status` shows nfsd running...